# How can I initialize a list string property without throwing a null exception?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, square-connect

I have an MVC controller with a jsonResult that transfers a session cart to Squares CreateOrderRequestLineItem List, but when I Initialize the list the code throws a null exception for quantity because it is a required property. I've mapped the quantity and even straight up set it to a string value I set the property quantity but the null exception is thrown before the code even reaches the mapping. Do I need to set the quantity to not null or 0 if null somewhere? Here is my controller code.

The session cart builds a cart based off of a product class and product model with set values of productid, name, quantity, price, and tax.

How do I map to a new list if it throws a null exception before my code can reach the mapping?

Note: I added another List ItemDetail to transfer the session data after the null exception error was already thrown and this didn't work either.

Note two: when I don't use Square object references and just use my generic lists and return json my quantity shows up with no nulls for every item in my cart.

```
public JsonResult CheckoutRequest(string id)
    {
        List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
        List<ItemDetails> itemDetails = cart.Select(s => new ItemDetails
        {
            ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(s.Product.ProductID),
            Name = s.Product.Name,
            Price = s.Product.Price,
            Quantity = Convert.ToString(s.Quantity)
        }).ToList();

   var lineItems = itemDetails.Select(s => new CreateOrderRequestLineItem()
        { 
            Quantity = "1",
            Name = s.Name, 
            BasePriceMoney = new Money
            {
                Amount = s.Price,
                Currency = Money.CurrencyEnum.USD,
            },
            CatalogObjectId = Convert.ToString(s.ProductID),
        }).ToList();

          CreateOrderRequest order = new CreateOrderRequest
        {
            ReferenceId = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()),
            LineItems = lineItems
        };

        //  Configuration.Default.AccessToken = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

        var body = new CreateCheckoutRequest
        {
            IdempotencyKey = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()),
            Order = order,
            AskForShippingAddress = true,
            MerchantSupportEmail = "americanapparelusa@aol.com"
        };

       return Json(new
        {
            locationId,
            body
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Is this line throwing null reference/NRE: `List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"]`? Try putting null check against the session variable before casting to `List<Item>`.

Comment: Is the `Quantity` property of your ItemDetails class a `string` type ? Why ? Try to use the correct types. Use a numeric type to store numeric data.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the following

```
List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
```

into

```
List<Item> cart  = new List<Item>();
if (Session["cart"] != null && Session["cart"].ToString() != null && Session["cart"].ToString() != "")
{                    
   cart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(Session["cart"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `Session` variable contains `List<Item>` which potentially has null value, you should use `as` operator and then check against null value:

```
var cart = Session["cart"] as List<Item>;
if (cart == null)
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // use mapping here
}
```

However if the `Session` variable contains JSON data, you can try casting as `string` type and deserialize it when available:

```
List<Item> cart = new List<Item>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["cart"] as string))
{
    cart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(Session["cart"].ToString());

    // use mapping here
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```